# How to filter logs in Grafana-Loki?

Tags: logging, prometheus, grafana-loki, promtail

I use the last versions of:

- **Prometheus**
- **prometheus-cpp library**
- **Grafana**
- **Loki**
- **Promtail**

in Windows 10.

So I just start bin files of these applications. And I get my **logfile.log** in Grafana panel.

[image: Grafana panels with Logs]

There are lines marked [INFO] in the log file. 
There may also be an [ERROR] mark. I want to be able to filter rows in a panel. For example, how can I display only lines marked with [ERROR] in the panel?

Answer (score 10):

One can use line filters to accomplish that:

```
|= : Log line contains string.
!= : Log line does not contain string.
|~ : Log line matches regular expression.
!~ : Log line does not match regular expression.
```

For instance:

A given log line from target cluster and app contains the string `ERROR`:

```
{cluster="my-dev-cluster", app="my-app"} |= "ERROR"
```

A given log line from target cluster and app contains the string `ERROR` but does not contain the string "TIMEOUT":

```
{cluster="my-dev-cluster", app="my-app"} |= "ERROR" != "TIMEOUT"
```

See more in this [cheat-sheet](https://megamorf.gitlab.io/cheat-sheets/loki/).

Answer (score 2):

Loki indexes logs by their labels. When you query Loki you must first specify a stream filter in the format `{<label><operator><value>}`. I'm guessing you're already aware of this since you've got your logs being displayed there, probably with something like `{app="vocoder"}`. You can then filter the stream of logs by plain text or regular expression with something like `{app="vocoder"} |= "[ERROR]"` (see the [Log queries documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/#line-filter-expression)). If you configure your Promtail scrapers to extract additional labels from the log messages (see [Labels documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/fundamentals/labels/#cardinality) and [Scraping documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/scraping/)), then you can also write stream filter expressions based on this, or filter based on this labels as part of your filter pipeline: `{app="vocoder"} | level = "error"`.

Comment: +1 to what @Paul said. You can use LogQL in Grafana's Explore view https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/explore/ and play around with filtering your logs.